# Android - Access and backup sqlite database before upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

I have developed an android application.

I have written the backup and restore procedures for database. but sometimes i need to backup data before the database version is upgraded due to possible bugs in new version of application, and ability to downgrade to previous version.

how and when can i access the database file before the OnUpgrade() function be called?

Comment: Why can't you do it at the beginning of `onUpgrade()`?

Comment: is database on previous version inside OnUpgrade?

Comment: You can do it in onUpgrade() method. Such stuff (like transitions\backups) should be done there.

Comment: Thank you all. i will test it.